# Why are nodes and nodal sets called this way?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, terminology, mathematical-physics

Nodes of standing waves are points where they are zero. Generally, nodal sets of Laplacian eigenfunctions are the sets of points where they are zero.

Why is this the name for them (that is, why is the English word "node" used)?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Seems to me simply because such points look like nodes. We say "knopen" in Dutch and Google finds that "nodes" is the English translation of that. What is you native language?

Comment: My native language is Hebrew. What do you mean by that they "look like nodes"? What does a node look like?

Answer (score 0):

What does a node look like? Let Google be your friend and search for 
[Pictures of nodes in waves](https://www.google.nl/search?q=nodes+waves&newwindow=1&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=1NtNVeHkLLCQ7AarqoHwCw&ved=0CDQQsAQ&biw=1920&bih=1017) or more general: **[Pictures of nodes](https://www.google.nl/search?q=pictures+of+nodes&newwindow=1&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=V91NVYzRNeTg7QaM7oHQDg&ved=0CCEQsAQ&biw=1920&bih=1017)**, and find some waves between these.